# copyright or convention in pip naming

Tags: python, pip

When I try to install janitor using

> pip install janitor

Some unexpected module gets installed:

https://github.com/yoloseem/janitor

In order to install the correct one, I need to change my pip command to:

> pip install pyjanitor

Is there any-way to fix this so that I can install pyjanitor using the name "janitor"?

Comment: you can read about some issues here https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/09/devs-unknowingly-use-malicious-modules-put-into-official-python-repository/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention is that anyone can register a name he likes.
Unless there really is an intellectual property right issue (there likely is not for names that cannot become trademarks), the people who see their name taken by another active project, will have to think of a new name.

> [The maintainers of the Package Index are not arbiters in disputes
>   around active projects.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0541/)

If you do not like to depend on the Python Package Index *PyPI* and the names registered there, either:

1. **Do not use it in cases you know better what you want to install anyway:**

   `pip install git+https://github.example/user/repo.git#commithash`

   Pip can install directly from many sources.
2. **Create your own Package Index:**

   In which case you can rename Packages however you wish. There are tools to ease this process, such as *[pip2pi](https://pypi.org/project/pip2pi/)*.

Carefully investigate whether the work of setting 2. up and maintaining it really is important to your organization (or rather just a simple step that should be properly *automated* on your dev & production machines, hiding any complexity in *package <> name* relationships)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any-way to fix this so that I can install pyjanitor using the name "janitor"?

No.